# Mic input volume is inconsistent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in which the player moves a certain distance compared to the players volume. For example. If the player whispers in real life the character in the game would move a little, and if the player shouts the character would move a lot. I have the code working but it produces a lot of inconsistent results.

Sometimes a whisper is apparenty louder than shouting and vice versa. I have used this code that i found online but i dont understand the math that's in it. Can anybody help me?

```
private void Awake()
{
    //init microphone input
    if (Microphone.devices.Length > 0)
    {
        microphoneInput = Microphone.Start(Microphone.devices[0], true, 999, 44100);

        microphoneInitialized = true;
    }
    else
    {
        print("There is no mic availiable");
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (microphoneInitialized == true)
    {
        // get mic volume
        int dec = 128;
        float[] waveData = new float[dec];
        int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (dec + 1); // null means the first microphone
        microphoneInput.GetData(waveData, micPosition);


        //Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
        float levelMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dec; i++)
        {
            float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
            if (levelMax < wavePeak)
            {
                levelMax = wavePeak;
            }
        }

        float db =  Mathf.Abs(levelMax) ;
        micInputVolume = db;// Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Sqrt(levelMax) * 100);           
    }

    //print("Mic volume = " + micInputVolume);
}
```

Comment: are you sure the peak is measuring volume not wave frequency?

Comment: To be honest mate. I have no idea nor have any idea how to properly check that

Comment: Hmm while Im not a mic expert it just struck me that when people yell usually the pitch is higher..  the unity doc does sort of suggest that its volume, but, then its not clear where the frequencies are stored.  for debugging, why not playback the sound recorded see if theres some form of distortion or interfearance

Comment: @BugFinder it is Amplitude between `-1` and `1` like the PCM format.

Comment: Your maths is a bit strange! 

You are using `waveData[i] * waveData[i]` which will always be positive amyway so later using `Mathf.Abs` is redundant.

Inside the `for` you could simply use `levelMax = Mathf.Max(levelMax, waveData[I] * waveData[I]);` 

Now note that this will make anything lower then `1` significantly smaller since e.g. `0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25` Maybe that's what causing the issue?

Comment: Looks fine to me. I would suggest doing some debugging by playing back the last clip when you detect high volumes by geting an `AudioSource` then doing `AudioClip sampleClip = AudioClip.Create("sample", dec, microphoneInput.channels, microphoneInput.frequency, false);` `sampleClip.SetData(waveData,0);` `audioSource.clip = sampleClip;` `audioSource.Play();`.

Comment: I think it might also help if you added the rest of tyour code where you actually use the `micInputVolume`